# cordova-plugin-filepath: Unable to resolve filesystem path

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Trying to upload image from ionic application using **cordova-plugin-camera** via android/ios gallery.
It's working perfectly fine on ios but throw error while resolving path, I'm using **cordova-plugin-filepath** for resolving file path.

But it always throw following error while resolving native path in ***this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)*** method:

```
{code: 0 ; message: "Unable to resolve filesystem path."}
```

Here is my code for uploading image:

```
var options = {
  quality: 60,
  targetWidth:900,
  sourceType: sourceType,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  correctOrientation: true
};


// Get the data of an image
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
  if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
    console.log('image path',imagePath)
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
      .then(res => {
        let correctPath = res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).toString();
        let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.length).toString();
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('unable to resolve file path issue', err)
      });
  } else {
    var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(currentName,correctPath)
    this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I have even tried using following code but no success:

```
window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
      .then(res => {
        let correctPath = res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).toString();
        let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.length).toString();
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('unable to resolve file path issue', err)
      });
```

Here are my plugin details:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.4.2" />
```

Ionic info:

`ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 15 other plugins)
System:
   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.4
   NodeJS            : v9.11.1
   npm               : 6.0.1
   OS                : Windows 10"`

Comment: It's seems like an android version issue, i just tested in android 5.1 version and it was working perfectly fine but not working on android 8.0 version

Comment: Same problem for Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the `file://` to the imagePath will do.

**Code Snippet**

```html
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
  if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
  //insert this line will solve the error
  imagePath = 'file://' + imagePath;
    console.log('image path',imagePath)
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
      .then(res => {
        let correctPath = res.substr(0, res.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).toString();
        let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.length).toString();
        this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('unable to resolve file path issue', err)
      });
  } else {
    var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(currentName,correctPath)
    this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**Explanation**

The previous code u write only available for the android version below android version 9.For the android version 9 and above couldn't recognized the file-path.